# R- Create a variable that is conditional upon row values

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe test that looks like this:

```
ID  Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4  Month5  Month6  Month7  Month8
    A   0       1      1       1       1        0       0        0
    B   0       1      1       1       0        0      NA        NA
    C   0       0      0       0       NA      NA      NA        NA
    D   0       1      1       1       1        1       1        1
    E   0       1      1       0       0        0       1        1
    F   0       0      0       1       1        1       1        1
    G   0       0      1       1       0        0       0        0
    H   0       0      0       0       0        0       0        0
```

I want to create a conditional variable “Result” within the data frame that counts the number of times 1 is repeated in a row. However, I only want to count the first set of 1s that is followed by a 0, which means that there are three conditions that I need to keep in mind when crating the “Result” variable.
 The conditions are as follows:

Condition 1:
Count the first set of 1s  that end with a 0.

Condition 2: 
If the set of 1s does not end in 0 or ends in NA, Result=NA

Condition 3
If there are two sets of 1s that end in the zero, ignore the second one.

```
ID  Month1  Month2  Month3  Month4  Month5  Month6  Month7  Month8  Result 
    A   0       1      1       1       1        0       0        0       4
    B   0       1      1       1       0        0      NA        NA      3
    C   0       0      0       0       NA      NA      NA        NA     0
    D   0       1      1       1       1        1       1        1      NA
    E   0       1      1       0       0        0       1        1      2
    F   0       0      0       1       1        1       1        1      NA
    G   0       0      1       1       0        0       0        0      2
    H   0       0      0       0       0        0       0        0      0
```

This that I have tried so far:

```
test$Result=apply(test[,c(2:9)],1,function(x) length(x[x==1&!(is.na(x))]))
```

this counts the total number of 1 in the row and not just the first set of ones.

Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using `rle()` to calculate `lengths of runs of values would be helpful here. Here's how i'm assiming your data is stored in R

```
dd <- structure(list(ID = structure(1:8, .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
    "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), class = "factor"), Month1 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Month2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), Month3 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Month4 = c(1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Month5 = c(1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L), Month6 = c(0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Month7 = c(0L, 
    NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Month8 = c(0L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L)), .Names = c("ID", "Month1", "Month2", "Month3", "Month4", 
    "Month5", "Month6", "Month7", "Month8"), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Then I would run code like

```
dd$Result <- apply(dd[, -1], 1, function(x) {
    rr<-rle(x)
    f1<-which(rr$values==1)[1]
    if ( is.na(f1) ) {
        0
    } else if (!is.na(rr$values[f1+1]) && rr$values[f1+1]==0) {
        rr$lengths[f1]
    } else {
        NA
    }
})
```

which gives

```
  ID Month1 Month2 Month3 Month4 Month5 Month6 Month7 Month8 Result
1  A      0      1      1      1      1      0      0      0      4
2  B      0      1      1      1      0      0     NA     NA      3
3  C      0      0      0      0     NA     NA     NA     NA      0
4  D      0      1      1      1      1      1      1      1     NA
5  E      0      1      1      0      0      0      1      1      2
6  F      0      0      0      1      1      1      1      1     NA
7  G      0      0      1      1      0      0      0      0      2
8  H      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

as you desired.

You do have a few edges cases that made this code somewhat tricky. First we have to see of there are any 1's; if not, we return 0. Then if there is a one, we want to make sure it's followed by a 0, otherwise return `NA`. We perform this logic for each row with an `apply()`, leaving off the ID column. It's not entirely clear from your description what should happen with `NA` values if they appear before the end of the row (like at the beginning) so i'll just assume that's a case you don't have to worry about.

Comment: That is correct, I do not have to look at cases in which NAs appear before 1s. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should work although there may be a tidier solution:

```
FindResult = function(x)
{
    RLE = rle(x)
    i = which(RLE$values == 1)[1]
    if(is.na(i))
        return(0)

    if (length(RLE$values) > i & RLE$values[i + 1] == 0)
        return(RLE$lengths[i])
    else
        return(NA)
}

Result = apply(df[,-1], 1, FindResult)
> Result
[1]  4  3  0 NA  2 NA  2  0
```

Comment: Hehe. It's quote surprising how similar our code ended up given that i changed my mind a few times in working toward a solution.